# Pick a random number but not the number 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

What would you add to make it so it still picks a random number but not the number 3?

```
- (IBAction)Button3 {
{
    int randomviews = rand() % 6;
    Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomviews];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another way to do it with just a single call to `rand()`.  Since you're excluding one number from your range, request a smaller range of numbers and then replace any generated 3's with the top number of the previous range:

```
- (IBAction)Button3 {
{
    int randomviews = rand() % 5;
    if (randomviews == 3) {
        randomviews = 5
    }
    Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomviews];
}
```

Comment: This is a far superior solution to the one involving a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)Button3 {
    int randomviews;

    do {
        randomviews = rand() % 6;
    }
    while (randomviews == 3);
    Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomviews];
}
```

If you would like to exclude zero as well:

```
- (IBAction)Button3 {
    int randomviews;

    do {
        randomviews = rand() % 6;
    }
    while (randomviews == 3 || randomviews == 0);
    Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomviews];
```

Comment: When i do this i get an error. The error is "Comparison between pointer and integer". What can fix this?

Comment: while (random !=3) should be while (randomviews !=3)

Comment: @Jacob It should be `while (randomviews == 3);`.  And I think you had an autocorrect issue because there is a space in randomviews.

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be `==` not `!=`. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks guys. Also how would you exclude 0 as well as the original 3 at the same time?

Comment: @ZaneF you would add || randomviews == 0 to the do statement.

Comment: if possible could you please write out the do statement. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why loop when a simple `if` statement check is all that's needed??